# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in ReactJS App

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, syntax-error

When i get to a specific page in my react application and I refresh it, I get a series of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title> Curator </title>
  <meta content="" name="description">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="assets/img/curator-favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Jost:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
  <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <Home></Home>


  <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
  <script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/waypoints/noframework.waypoints.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>

  <!-- Template Main JS File -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

  

  <!-- Aggiungi questi script nella sezione head del tuo file HTML -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

<!-- Aggiungi questi script prima della chiusura del tag body del tuo file HTML -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js" type = "text/babel"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" type = "text/babel"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.12.3/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" type = "text/babel"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my HTML. I've tried, like other users suggested, adding a

```
script type= text/babel
```

but what happens is that the Landing page of my website doesn't show anything. How could i fix this?

Comment: The babel standalone package is missing? https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-standalone